# Asp.Net Core 3.1 OData doesn't work with attribute routing and function with parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-3.1

Is it possible to achieve the following route with Asp.Net Core 3.1 and Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData version 7.3.0:

```
/ParentEntity({id})/Children(OnlyActive={onlyActive})
```

**What I've achieved:**

The controller's method:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("ParentEntity({id})/Children")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Children([FromODataUri] string id)
{
    // some data fetching operations.
}
```

With the following model configuration:

```
builder.EntityType<ParentEntity>().Function("Children")
                .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<ChildEntity>("ChildEntity");
```

Works fine and I'm can get id parameter in Children method.

But when I'm trying to do something like:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("ParentEntity({id})/Children(OnlyActive={onlyActive})")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Children([FromODataUri] string id, [FromODataUri] bool onlyActive)
{
   // some data fetching operations.
}
```

With model configuration:

```
FunctionConfiguration getFunc = builder.EntityType<ParentEntity>().Function("Children")
                    .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<ChildEntity>("ChildEntity");

getFunc.Parameter<bool>("OnlyActive");
```

I'm getting the error:

> Microsoft.OData.ODataException: 'Bad Request - Error in query syntax'

Is it possible to use Odata functions this way? Or should I try another approach?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this behavior by **specifying 'Deafult' namespace** in path in `ODataRoute` attribute.

After a lot of trying this worked for me:

```
[HttpGet]
[ODataRoute("ParentEntity({id})/Default.Children(OnlyActive={onlyActive})")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Children([FromODataUri]string id, [FromODataUri]bool onlyActive)
```

Model configuration:

```
FunctionConfiguration getFunc = builder.EntityType<ParentEntity>().Function("Children")
                    .ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<ChildEntity>("ChildEntity");

getFunc.Parameter<bool>("OnlyActive");
```

I found the example of bound function with parameters in [this tutorial](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/tutorial-sample-functions-actions-in-web-api-v2-2-for-odata-v4-0-type-scenario/#route-bound-functions) by [Sam Xu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3304931/sam-xu).